# Detect file type and resize if image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I have model Attachment whitch supprted pdf's and images. How to detect if its image and only then resize it ? When it's paperclip everything Was simple. but now ? ;)

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base

        has_attached_file :attachment,
                styles:          lambda { |a| a.instance.is_image? ? {:small => "x200>", :medium => "x300>", :large => "x400>"}  : {:thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg'}, :medium => { :geometry => "300x300#", :format => 'jpg'}}},

        def is_image?
                attachment.instance.attachment_content_type =~ %r(image)
        end

end
```

How to make something like above with active storage ? I try like this:

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :file
  validates :file, presence: true

def file_url
if ???? (is image?)
rails_blob_url(file.variant(resize: '1920x1920').processed)
else
rails_blob_url(file)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

ActiveStorage has build in helpers for popular content-types like: image, video, audio etc. For image is `image?`:

```
if file.image?
  rails_representation_url(file.variant(resize: '1920x1920').processed)
else
  rails_blob_url(file)
end
```

Api docs: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-image-3F

`audio?, image?, text?, video?`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and.. What it is "signed_id" ?

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `signed_id' for #<ActiveStorage::Variant:0x00007fb67a4325f0>):

activestorage (5.2.0) config/routes.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:641:in `instance_exec'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:641:in `eval_block'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:630:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:164:in `block (2 levels) in add_url_helper'
app/models/attachment.rb:27:in `file_url'
app/serializers/api/v1/attachment_serializer.rb:7:in `file_url'
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention, for variant generated url, you need to use `rails_representation_url` instead of `rails_blob_url`. I've updated my answer

Comment: representation_url gives url only one time ? - i got url after upload and when i want show it from browser again its return 404 - why ?

Comment: you mean `representation_url` returns some url, and after you enter it in browser it's return 404? Whats the url looks like? Are you displaying this image in views?